# Problema con carpeta antigua server web

Tags: web, moodle

Buen dia.

Que tal compañeros, tengo un problema con una migración que realice de moodle en windows a linux centos, he realizado todos los procesos correspondientes, pero ya al final, cuando carga la pagina me aparece esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la linea Ruta de acceso fisica, me aparece `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`, cuando deberia aparecer `/var/www/Sitios`,  ya que este fue el que configure en el config.php de moodle, pero aun asi sigue buscando la ruta del anterior servidor IIS de windows, por que razon pasa esto?

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega la configuración que le has realizado al IIS. Recuerda ocultar información sensible, tal y como lo has hecho con el color azul sobre los nombres de la Dirección URL solicitada y Ruta de acceso física.

Comment: Y qué guarda moodle en BD de configuración? Pregunto como para guiar la revisión porque no lo conozco :)

Comment: Pero ya no tengo la aplicacion en el ISS lo tengo en un apache centos, en el config.php ya edite las lineas, $CFG->dataroot  = '/var/www/html/Sit/Sal/moodledata'; y $CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/eduPlatform'; pero el dataroot no quiere actualizar, donde puedo cambiar esto?

Comment: en ese caso, reinicia el apache. Si la IP del servidor web ha cambiado, pide al admin de red que actualice el DNS apuntando a la IP correcta.